# Can't seem to install a python package

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I have been trying to install a python package called "pywhatkit". When I run `pip install pywhatkit` it installs it, but PyCharm says it can't find the module. I've been running my project in an anaconda environment, so I thought installing it from the anaconda command prompt would fix the issue. I ran this command in Anaconda Powershell Prompt:

```
 python -m pip install pywhatkit
```

then I got this message:

```
Downloading/unpacking pywhatkit
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pywhatkit
No distributions at all found for pywhatkit
Storing complete log in C:\Users\wave computer\pip\pip.log
```

I have Googled this problem but can't find anything. I'm using Windows 10 and python version 3.9. My pip version is 21.0.1.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Edit: When I do `conda info`, i get this:

```
 active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Anaconda
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\wave computer\.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : 3.20.5
         python version : 3.8.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Anaconda  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Anaconda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\wave computer\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\wave computer\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Anaconda\envs
                          C:\Users\wave computer\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\wave computer\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

I hope this is of some help.

**Edit 2:**
As I've mentioned earlier I'm using a Conda environment. Even when I have Conda package manager enabled, it can't find pywhatkit.

[image: a screenshot of PyCharm]

Comment: are you using the right virtual enviroment?

Comment: i'm not sure. how can i check?

Comment: I think 'conda info'  in terminal, or '%conda info' in jupyter note book would work.

Comment: i edited my question. please take a look at it again. thank you!

Comment: Can you try running "pip install pywhatkit" instead? https://datatofish.com/how-to-install-python-package-in-anaconda/

Comment: python3 -m pip install pywhatkit

Comment: @dimi_fn when i did "pip install pywhatkit" it shows requirement already satisfied, then ends. but when try to import it in Pycharm it shows "no module named pywhatkit". i have no idea where to go from here

Comment: @CrashtestEnigma, then there might be a mismatch in the path, "since requirement already satisfied". You are trying to install the package via anaconda, hence check if your interpreter path at PyCharm has the anaconda path https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/#configuring-a-conda-environment-in-pycharm

Comment: @dimi_fn i did this, but to no avail. i'm running my project in a conda environment, and my interpreter is an anaconda interpreter. i can't see what's wrong here.

Comment: run `conda list` see if you can find pywhatkit

Comment: type `python` to go into python shell, then type `import pywhatkit` see if it works .

Comment: @amirshakiba yes, it is there! i don't understand why PyCharm can't find it

Comment: @amirshakiba after typing ```python``` in the anaconda prompt then typing ```import pywhatkit```, it shows this:
 ```Hello from the creator of pywhatkit, Ankit Raj Mahapatra.
Kindly do report bugs if any
What's new:
1. Fixed text_to_handwriting() function.
2. Added pywhatkit.headless_pyk.sendwhatmsg(...), with this, you don't need to keep your computer on after scheduling.
3. Added feature to schedule message for a group.```

but nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

pycharm works inside an environment which may be different from the base environment.

the reason is simple each project should run in it's own environment so different projects with different dependencies don't conflict with each other.
if you want to use terminal , first you should run `activate yourEnviromentName` then run `pip install yourpackagename`.
If you want to use pycharm you can do it as follows:

To manage Python packages for the Python interpreter, select the Python Interpreter page in the project Settings/Preferences or select Interpreter Settings in the Python Interpreter selector on the Status bar.

If you select a Python interpreter with the configured Conda environment, the Use Conda Package Manager toggle appears in the packages area toolbar.

now go to package toolbar and search for your package and install it!

Comment: it didn't work. i just added a screenshot to my question, please take a look at it and let me know what's wrong. thank you.

Comment: On Windows, if you have already have the virtualenvironment eg. 'myvenv' located within the project root, you can activate it from the terminal as below:`.\myvenv\Scripts\activate` where activate is a batch file i guess. You know it is activated when you see the change:

`C:\Projects\........\MyProject>`

to
`(myvenv)C:\Projects\Trunk\MyProject>`
now type `pip install pywhatkit`

Comment: i don't understand. what is this virtual environment for?

Comment: @CrashtestEnigma  you may have many projects with different dependencies.for example you may use `openCV` with one `numpy` package on one project and `tensorflow` with another version of `numpy` on another project . virtual environments help avoid conflict.